# Checking correctness of site

Tags: validation

I am looking for a way to thoroughly check my site against common errors (like 404 links, duplicated title tags and so on). I'd like to define some custom rules too, for example:

- We changed name of our product. So I would like to define a rule that any instance of "OldName" generates a warning (except at some predefined pages which actually refer to differences between old product and new one).
- I'd like to ensure that all instances of our company name or product name are properly marked as trademarked. So any instance of "CompanyName" that is not followed by a unicode character "TM" should generate a warning.

I know that some basic checks can be made through Google Webmaster Tools or similar, but it is slow and does not check many things.

I am now using a custom home-made crawler, but maybe there are better choices?

It doesn't have to be free. It can be a SAAS or an installable app.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of tools out there but I would check out these:

1. Microsoft's [SEO Toolkit](http://www.iis.net/download/seotoolkit) it is part of IIS7 and on.  It will check your entire site for duplicate Title tags, html errors, broken links, etc.  The one thing it won't do is allow you to make custom rules to check for misspellings etc.
2. Xenu's [Link sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) is also a great tool and is free.  Again it won't do everything you are looking for but it will do a lot of it.
3. Another option, specifically for spell checking is [NetMechanic](http://www.netmechanic.com/cobrands/FutureQuest/spell_check.htm).  It looks free and lets you use a custom library.  I have never used it so I cannot vouch for it.

It is highly unlikely that you will find 1 tool that is free and does everything you want. However, by combining tools you should be able to find a set that solves all of your issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for something more generic and amendable. As you said, there are tons of tools, but from what i see, most of them are crappy.

Comment: @Liori - Could you explain what you mean by generic?  There are definitely many bad tools out there but there are a few good ones that are free.  I use Msft's SEO Toolkit all the time and I love it.

Comment: I added some examples of what kind of functionality I am looking for to my question.